# Enumerations in Constructors (architecture-dependent error)

Tags: c++, gcc, enums, c++14, 32bit-64bit

## Code and Goal

I am using an enumeration value in an object's constructor. The enumerator is declared public in the abstract `Base` class, and used in the constructors for the `Derived1` and `Derived2` classes.

Here's the "foo'd" version of the code, omitting the non-important stuff. (I have MUCH better names in the real version, but they'd only muddy the waters here.)

> NOTE: Annoyingly enough, this *near*-MCVE duplicates all the LOGIC involved, but the problem doesn't surface. I'll leave it here in case anyone recognizes the issue while I continue deeper debugging - the actual code is massive and highly interconnected, so I'm basically filleting a whale with a steak knife here. Please be patient as I try to narrow it down and duplicate the problem! >.> (And please don't DV for lack of a full MCVE right now - I'm working as fast as I can, but I don't know if someone recognizes this weirdness in the meantime.)

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "TestClass.h"

class Base : public OtherBase
{
    public:
        enum TestArrayType
        {
            ARRAY_RANDOM,
            ARRAY_SORTED,
            ARRAY_REVERSED
            //Actually, there are about 20 more values here...
        };

    protected:
        TestArrayType arrayType;
        //More member functions and variables...

    public:
        Base(){}
        bool pre()
        {
            // Do some magic....

            switch(arrayType)
            {
                case ARRAY_RANDOM:
                {
                    // Case specific magic...
                    break;
                }
                case ARRAY_SORTED:
                {
                    // More case specific magic...
                    break;
                }
                case ARRAY_REVERSED:
                {
                    // You get the idea.
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //More stuff here...
        }
        virtual bool run()
        {
            return true;
        }
        ~Base(){}

};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived1(TestArrayType type = ARRAY_RANDOM)
        {
            arrayType = type;
        }
        bool run()
        {
            // Do derived-class-specific magic.
            return true;
        }
        ~Derived1(){}

};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived2(TestArrayType type = ARRAY_RANDOM)
        {
            arrayType = type;
        }
        bool run()
        {
            // Do derived-class-specific magic.
            return true;
        }
        ~Derived2(){}
};

int main()
{

    //someFunction is using std::unique_ptr.
    testclass.someFunction("Derived1", new Derived1(Base::ARRAY_SORTED));
    testclass.someFunction("Derived2", new Derived2(Base::ARRAY_SORTED));

    return 0;
}
```

**TestClass.h**

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H

#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

class OtherBase
{
    public:
        OtherBase(){}

        virtual bool pre(){return true;}
        virtual bool run()=0;

        virtual ~OtherBase(){}
};

class TestClass
{
    public:
        TestClass(){}

        void someFunction(std::string, OtherBase*);

        ~TestClass(){}
    protected:
        typedef std::unique_ptr<OtherBase> test_ptr;
        std::map<std::string, test_ptr> stuff;
};

extern TestClass testclass;

#endif // TESTCLASS_H
```

**TestClass.cpp**

```
#include "TestClass.h"

//Declaring global instance of testclass.
TestClass testclass;

void TestClass::someFunction(std::string name, OtherBase* test)
{
    if(test == 0)
    {
        //Show error.
        //Return non-fatally.
        return;
    }

    //Stuff is a map
    stuff.emplace(name, test_ptr(test));
}
```

## Environment

- Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit (AMD)
- Code::Blocks 16.01
- `g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~15.10) 5.2.1 20151028`
- Compiling against `--std=c++14`.
- I have `gcc-5-multilib` and `g++-5-multilib` installed, and everything is up-to-date as of this morning.

## Problem

This works perfectly when compiling with `-m64` - no warnings, errors, or other issues.

However, when compiling with `-m32`, I get the following errors on each use of `new` with the derived classes and enumerations...

> undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int)'

There are similar errors coming from `someFunction`, but those all related back to the above error's cause (they have the same complaint).

**Successful build command (64-bit):**

```
g++ -std=c++14 -fexceptions -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -lsigc-2.0 -Wextra -Wall -g -m64 -v -I../pawlib/Debug64/include -c /home/jason/Code/Repositories/pawlib-git/pawlib-tester/main.cpp -o obj/Debug64/main.o
```

**Problem build command (64-bit):**

```
g++ -std=c++14 -fexceptions -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -lsigc-2.0 -Wextra -Wall -g -m32 -v -I../pawlib/Debug32/include -c /home/jason/Code/Repositories/pawlib-git/pawlib-tester/main.cpp -o obj/Debug32/main.o
```

Repeating for emphasis: **this code is working perfectly when compiled with `-m64`**.

Comment: This probably isn't related, but you should also be making your base class's destructor `virtual`

Comment: @kfsone, I added `someFunction`, though it is HEAVILY without context. It is in a rather massive bit of code, so take my word for it that this is the most efficient way of doing things atm. I'll keep your idea in mind, tho.

Comment: @derekerdmann, I'll bear that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: [MCVE] needed; minimal project that when compiled produces your symptom.  This needs to include all command-line flags you feed the compiler, and compiler version information.  I'm guessing you have a library messup somewhere.

Comment: Does the shown piece of code triggers the error? If yes, try cutting away pieces until it doesn't: see what exactly causes the problem. (If no, we have nothing to do here)

Comment: None of the code you posted fails to compile for the reason you mentioned. You have missing variable declaration, you've posted `someFunction` after `main`, and you've called `someFunction` with insufficient arguments (it appears you need a `std::string` and then a `Derived*`, but you only pass a `Derived*`). Please get your code to a state where we can reproduce your problem. Bonus points for linking to it from an online compiler (coliru and ideone are commonly used here).

Comment: Hey all, sorry about that. Turns out, it's going to take a while to nail down a legible MCVE - the code is MASSIVE (see note in edit above). I fixed the typos and expanded the example, which I'll leave here in case anyone happens to recognize this weird behavior. Meanwhile, I'll keep trying to boil down the code (easier said than done).

Comment: FYI, I'm switching away from `libsigc++` because of a host of there-but-not-there type bugs, so I'm beginning to suspect that library may be indirectly causing some evil to occur. Once I've switched, it will be a LOT easier to narrow in on a better MCVE.